# How to retrieve the third uri segment in a codeigniter hook

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-hooks

I'm writing a custom post_controller hook. As we know, codeigniter uri structure is like this:

```
example.com/class/function/id/
```

and my code:

```
function hook_acl()
{
    global $RTR;
    global $CI;

    $controller = $RTR->class; // the class part in uri
    $method = $RTR->method; // the function part in uri
    $id = ? // how to parse this?

    // other codes omitted for brevity
}
```

I've browsed the core Router.php file, which puzzled me a lot.

thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Using CodeIgniter URI core class

Generally within CodeIgniter **Hooks**, we need to load/instantiate the URI core class to reach the methods.

- For `post_controller_constructor`, `post_controller`, ... hooks, we can get the CodeIgniter super object and use use the `uri` class:

```php
# Get the CI instance
$CI =& get_instance();

# Get the third segment
$CI->uri->segment(3);
```

- **But** for `pre_controller` hook, we don't have access to CodeIgniter *super object* So we have to load the URI core class manually as follows:

```php
# Load the URI core class
$uri =& load_class('URI', 'core');

# Get the third segment
$id = $uri->segment(3); // returns the id
```

### Using pure PHP

In this approach you can use `$_SERVER` array to fetch the URI segments as:

```php
$segments = explode('/', trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/'));

$controller = $segments[1];
$method     = $segments[2];
$id         = $segments[3];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `router` class :

```
$this->router->fetch_class();
$this->router->fetch_method();
```

Or the [URI](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/uri.html) class :

```
$this->uri->segment(1); // the class
$this->uri->segment(2); // the function
$this->uri->segment(3); // the ID
```

Comment: Thank you, it works. (use `$CI->uri->segment(3);`). Codeigniter already have a class ready for use. I should read CI userguide more carefully.