# Can not access to codeigniter superobject into the hooks and uri

Tags: php, codeigniter, hook

I first call a super object and add this contractor

```
$this->CI =& get_instance();
```

but when I want to access

```
print_r($this->CI->router->fetch_class());
```

it shows the error 
`Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to retrieve the third uri segment in a codeigniter hook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22300596/how-to-retrieve-the-third-uri-segment-in-a-codeigniter-hook)

Comment: @splash58 Oops, that 's not working yet. );